# Docker swarm redis network issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, docker-swarm

I have created a docker swarm cluster in gcp with 3 nodes.

The redis container is running on manager.
However each service that runs on nodes cannot connect to redis container.

This happens only for redis and not for other services.

`version: "3.8"
services:   redis:
image: redis
ports:

- 6379:6379
  networks:
- services
  volumes:
- /opt/redis:/data
  deploy:
  restart_policy:
  condition: on-failure
  delay: 5s
  max_attempts: 3
  window: 120s
  placement:
  constraints:
- node.labels.type == manager
  networks:
  services:`

I have opened the ports in gcp firewall.
I have tried to run telnet inside the container.

Comment: By default, the VPC firewall allows internal traffic. The rule name is `default-allow-internal`. Unless you have modified or deleted that rule, the firewall is not your problem. Your question does not have details to help you. Show the configuration files and how the connection is made to Redis.

Comment: I have used the following yml file for redis: @JohnHanley
version: "3.8"

`services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - services
    volumes:
      - /opt/redis:/data
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.type == manager
networks:
  services:`

And i use redis host to connect inside the nodejs app

Comment: Please edit your post with details. Do not use comments for items that require formatting to be understood accurately.

Comment: i have also installed redis-cli inside a docker in worker, and run `ping redis`. It works but when i try `redis-cli -h redis`, it hangs

Comment: There is a lot more to configuring Docker Swarm than you included in your comment. Most likely you have misconfigured Docket networking and you do not show how that is configured.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have opened ports in gcp firewall :  
tcp:2377, 7946
udp:4789, 7946

Comment: Reread my first comment. Opening ports int the firewall is not necessary. If it is necessary show those details in your question and why.

Comment: @JohnHanley i have the default-allow-internal firewall rule

Comment: @JohnHanley after some hours of troubleshooting the problem was in mtu size . The vpc network has mtu 1450 and the docker network 1500.

Comment: The default VPC MTU is 1460 bytes. However, that can be configured [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/mtu). Please post an answer with your solution as that will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The gcloud network has 1460 mtu size and the docker network 1500 mtu size.
So i set the mtu in yaml file to 1460 and eventually it works.

networks:
services:
driver: overlay
driver_opts:
com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1460